# Write to multiple nodes in Firebase?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Once the user hits a "post" button, two things should happen:

1. a "comment" node is created
2. a "message" node is created

However, I can't seem to get it to write into firebase twice:

```
let ref = Database.database().reference()
let userProfile = UserService.currentUserProfile

let key = ref.child("post").childByAutoId().key

let feed = ["comment": commentView.text,
            "username": uid,
            "timestamp": [".sv":"timestamp"],
            "author": [
                "cid": userProfile?.uid,
                "username": userProfile?.username,
                "fullname": userProfile?.fullname,
                "patthToImage": userProfile?.patthToImage.absoluteString]] as [String : Any]

let commentFeed = ["\(key!)" : feed]
let commentorFeed = [uid: uid]
let commentFe = ["messages": feed]

// my comment node, which is working         

ref.child("posts").child(myPost).child("comment").updateChildValues(commentFeed)
ref.child("posts").child(myPost).updateChildValues(commentorFeed)

//my message node which isn't working

let ches = Database.database().reference().child("messages")
ches.setValue("hahah")
```

is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

It's not an issue of saving values twice. It appears to be an issue with this code:

```
let ches = Database.database().reference().child("messages")
ches.setValue("hahah")
```

You need to instead use `push()`:

```
ref.child("messages").push("hahah")
```

Comment: In Swift that would be `ref.child("messages").childByAutoId().setValue("haha")`.

Comment: However: I'd consider not creating a child with a new unique ID, but instead reusing the key that was already generated for the post. So: `ref.child("messages").child(key).setValue("hahah")`.